# Allow commenting on front page?

Tags: comments

My client wants a comment section on the front page only. I can't figure out how to allow commenting on the front page. I tried allowing commenting on basic pages, but it wont show on the front.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Do you mean to allow users to comment on nodes shown in the front page, from the front page?

Comment: I thinks it shows the comment on front page.

Comment: @kiamlaluno No, you know how you can allow commenting on pages? Well how can I allow it for the home page?

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from `modules/comment/comment.module` inside `function comment_node_view($node, $view_mode)`:

```
// Only append comments when we are building a node on its own node detail
// page. We compare $node and $page_node to ensure that comments are not
// appended to other nodes shown on the page, for example a node_reference
// displayed in 'full' view mode within another node.
if ($node->comment && $view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node) && empty($node->in_preview)) {
  $node->content['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);
}
```

1. commenting for the node must be turned on
2. The node must be shown in the `full`-view_mode (normally this is `node/<nid>`)
3. `node_is_page()`: Whether the current page is the full page view of the passed-in node.
4. It must not be an edited preview of this node.

If you still feel like showing the comments on the frontpage for a specific node, try this:

```
$frontpage_commenting_node = node_load( **1** );
print render(comment_node_page_additions($frontpage_commenting_node));
```

Note: 
 - You need to change the parameter of node_load to the effective node id in your system.
 - This is for Drupal 7

Comment: This is not working. I tried putting the code in page--front.tpl.php and it spits out errors.